# How to host a silverlight application on https?

Tags: c#, silverlight, ssl, https

I am wondering how to host a silverlight app on https instead of http.

i am currently reading this article, which isnt helping :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Thanks

Comment: @Carko ive treid everything except the one that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These articles would *definitely* help you setting up ***Silverlight*** application to run over ***HTTPS/SSL*** with step by step approach:

1. [Hosting Silverlight Under HTTPS](http://www.i-m-code.com/blog/blog/2011/08/18/hosting-silverlight-under-https/)
2. [Setting up SSL between Silverlight and WCF under IIS7](http://geekswithblogs.net/scottthompson/archive/2009/03/25/setting-up-ssl-between-silverlight-and-wcf-under-iis7.aspx)
3. [Steps to make Silverlight enabled WCF service working under SSL protocol](http://sladapter.blogspot.com/2011/10/steps-to-make-silverlight-enabled-wcf.html)
4. [Setup Silverlight application with WCF service to run over HTTPS/SSL](http://dotnetspeak.com/index.php/2009/04/setup-silverlight-application-with-wcf-service-to-run-over-httpsssl/)

A detailed tutorial in this regard:

[Silverlight 4.0 - Calling Secured WCF 4.0 Service hosted with SSL and Self-Signed Certificate](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=589)

Comment: this only helped a very little ammount (if any at all) , but i beleive it will be useful for future people researching cross overs from http to https

Comment: @FSX This was actually very helpful to me after several hours of headaches trying to get it to work.  However, I do have an issue that it stops working if I select "Require SSL" in IIS Manager.  Any idea on that?